# Accessing custom control sub-controls via ID

Tags: asp.net

I am building a Custom Control for the first time, it is still in the making, but basically it is a composite custom control that contains a bunch of drop down menus and buttons. Thinking ahead, I got a problem, I will need to access some of these subcontrols via ID, but how will I know their ID? I cannot set them at design-time because then there will be many duplicate IDs, so how do I set/get them?

Thanks for any input,
Leo

Comment: You will get more help if you post some code sample here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare getter properties for them in Custom control, something like this :

```
public string InnerControlID 
{
  get
  {
    return innerControl.ID;
  }
}
```

ID can be set when you are creating this controls.